# Salesforce: no more storage because of "Interaction count reports"

Tags: salesforce

Under "setup->Storage Usage" I found I have used 110% of the data storage available. But 75% of this data storage is used by "Interaction count reports". I cannot find much information about this. I would like to delete those reports, but I cannot find them anywhere. Does anyone know where I can find them and how to delete them?

Answer (score 0):

It appears this is linked to using Digital Experiences (formerly Communities) and tracking of Chatter Post (Feed Item) data.

> Get a report on the top 100 feed item views in your organization or community with the primary object Interaction Count Report. Knowing the posts that people are looking at most is a great way to get insight into current Chatter trends. Actions counted as views include liking, commenting, and viewing a feed item detail. View counts aren’t unique. For example, a user can add three comments to a post, and that is counted as three views. After you set up the report, it’s run weekly.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.reports_chatter_top_views.htm&type=5

Answer (score 0):

FeedItem records (chatter posts) contributes towards this data storage. We encountered a similar issue in our sandbox org, and when we cleared old FeedItem records - the storage shown under 'Interaction Count Reports' got reduced.